# saving file on sd card, writes file size 0

Tags: android, image, file, sd-card

I have trouble with saving images on sd card. I can see the file on the sd card but file is empty (size 0). I tried saving it on the phone memory and it works fine. Here is my code.

```
    Imagewritter {

       public static boolean writeAsJPG(Context context, Bitmap bitmap,
    String filename) {
       filename = filename + ".jpg";
       File path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

    File f = new File(path, filename);
    FileOutputStream fos = null;

    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        fos = context.openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d(TAG, "file not found");
        return false;
    }

    bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, fos);
    try {
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "error closing");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
```

here is the code where the bitmap comes from.

```
    DrawingView = (drawing) findViewById(R.id.drawing_view);
    drawingBitmap = (Bitmap) DrawingView.getBitmap();
    String idName = timeStampText;
    //save Image as JPG
    ImageWritter.writeAsJPG(getApplicationContext(), drawingBitmap, idName);
```

Comment: Please post the code where the bitmap variable is actually set.  Also, dont allocate a new FileOutputStream.  That entire block of code is wasted because of the call to context.openFileOutput.

Comment: thanks for that. i'll add the code where the bitmap comes from

Comment: you're right. my code was redundant. I removed context.openFileOutput and it worked fine. thanks so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only problem here is that I have two lines for writing the file. Using FileOutputStream and OpenFileOutput. Just remove these lines and it'll be fine.

```
    try {
        fos = context.openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d(TAG, "file not found");
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

i think u have to add these permission in manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the image in byte array & check the size of that byte array.. I think you getting 0 size byte array.....

Comment: i dont think so, because when i saved image on its internal memory. it works just fine. im not getting 0 for its size.